# How can I make my contents go below the navigation controller without adjusting the content y position programmatically

Tags: swift

How can I make my contents go below the navigation controller without adjusting the content y position programmatically  . The reason I ask that is because when I adjust the content using y position  it look fine but when the device is rotated I get a white gap because the navigation bar height change.

[image: This is an image of adjust view y position portrait]
[image]

My code

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UINavigationController {


    let topProfileView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    view.backgroundColor = .white

        topProfileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(topProfileView)
        topProfileView.backgroundColor = .red
        topProfileView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        topProfileView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        topProfileView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        topProfileView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        topProfileView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant:44).isActive = true

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I present the view controller as a `UINavigationController` this will display the the nav bar

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the use of auto layout. 
Make the x and y position 0 of red view in auto layout

Comment: if i make them 0 they will go over the nav bar